# Get latest value from observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, observable

Is it possible to take just the latest element from an observable as if I was subscribing to it and use that value for an action?

I tried the code below but that does not work.

```
this.af.database.list('photos')
  .single()
  .do(res => console.log(res))
  //I want to navigate to another routerLink in the do statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm going to make an assumption. You would like the latest value of a long running observable.

To do this, you need to ensure that the observable is a BehaviorSubject (which always has an initial value ready for consumption), or has been made replayable using the publishReplay operator. When using publishReplay you get a ConnectableObserbable back, be sure to call connect.

Once this is done, you can use take(1) to restrict to a single element.

For instance lets say you want to take some action based on the most recent click location.

```
var source = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .publishReplay(1);
source.connect();
```

then later

```
source.take(1).subscribe(ev => console.log(`(${ev.clientX}, ${ev.clientY})`));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. In my example the observable is a pure observable as returned by Firebase in Angular2. Is it possible to replicate your pattern in that case?